# how to use HTML 5 data-attributes or variables for my left and right values?

Tags: jquery, animation

I have two animations which are practically identical... the difference between them is "left vs right" positioning. I would like to reuse the first block of code for both .forward and .backward... I'm guessing this could be done with the use of a HTML 5 data- attributes or maybe variables, but I'm not sure how to go about that.

Please advise this noob... thanks!

```
      .hover-area { position:relative; width:100%; height:50px; }
      .backward, .forward { position:absolute; }
      .backward{ left:0px; }
      .forward { right:0px; }​


      <div class="hover-area">
          Hover Area
          <div class="backward">Previous</div>
          <div class="forward">Next</div>
      </div>
```

```
        $('.forward').css({opacity:0, right:0});
        $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.forward').stop()
                .animate({right:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
                .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
        },function() {
            $(this).find('.forward').stop()
                .animate({right:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
                .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
        });




        $('.backward').css({opacity:0, left:0});
        $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
            $(this).find('.backward').stop()
                .animate({left:20}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
                .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
        },function() {
            $(this).find('.backward').stop()
                .animate({left:0}, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
                .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest (and most versatile) method may be to use HTML5 data-attributes to store the start/stop animation states as JSON data. Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ChrisPebble/LFsVr/

HTML

```
<div class="hover-area" data-animate-on='{"right":"20"}' data-animate-off='{"right":"0"}'>hover over me
    <div class="slider">I move to the right</div>
</div>

<div class="hover-area" data-animate-on='{"left":"20"}' data-animate-off='{"left":"0"}'>hover over me
    <div class="slider">I move to the left</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.slider').css({opacity:0, right:0});
$('.hover-area').hover(function() {
    var animationOn = jQuery.parseJSON(($(this).attr("data-animate-on")));
    $(this).find('.slider').stop()
        .animate(animationOn, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'})
        .animate({opacity:'0.95'}, {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'});
},function() {
    var animationOff = jQuery.parseJSON(($(this).attr("data-animate-off")));
    $(this).find('.slider').stop()
        .animate(animationOff, {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'})
        .animate({opacity:'0'}, {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'});
});
```

Comment: Is their any way could have one parent with two child elements? basically,"hover-area" would be the parent to both "slider". I will use this as left and right arrows in a slideshow, so I need both triggered when you hover over "hover-area"... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I wasnt too sure what structure of the html should be or what should happen, but is this the sort of thing you mean (in terms of variables?)?

```
var option = 'right'; // or option = 'left'
var classDirection = ".forward"; // or ".backward";
move(option, classDirection, 20);
function move(option, classDirection, changeDir}{
   var css = {opacity:0};

   var obj = {};
   obj[option] = 0;
   $.extend(css, obj); 

   var obj2 = {};
   obj2[option] = chaneDir;

   $(classDirection).css(css);
   $('.hover-area').hover(function() {
      $(this).find(classDirection)
      .stop()
      .animate(
           obj2, 
           {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutCubic'}
      ).animate(
           {opacity:'0.95'}, 
           {queue:false, duration:400, easing:'easeOutCubic'}
      );
   },
   function() {
       $(this).find(classDirection).stop()
       .animate(
           obj, 
           {queue:false, duration:550, easing:'easeOutSine'}
       ).animate(
           {opacity:'0'}, 
           {queue:false, duration:300, easing:'easeOutSine'}
       );
   });
}
```

​
I started a thing on jsfiddle if it helps. As for using data attributes (if you really want to), i think you can access them using $('.forward).attr('data-dir'); with  or something.

http://jsfiddle.net/zBsXX/1/

Comment: Here is the basic structure'<div class="hover-area">
    hover area
    <div class="forward">Forward</div>
</div>


<style>
.hover-area {
    position: relative;
}

.forward {
    position: absolute;
}

</style>'

Comment: Taylor, I would move forward with Chris Pebble's answer